# How to fill in the blank spaces in a PDF file using C# and MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, migradoc

Good day

I have a .pdf file that is filled in manually after printing it. Now I am digitizing this process. I want to be able to fill in the blank spaces in the file digitally. I am using C# and MigraDoc. I do not have a specific code to put here. May someone please point me to the right direction?

Siyabonga

Comment: @KJ They ask how to do it with MigraDoc, so the question does not violate the rules. But MigraDoc is the wrong tool to modify existing PDF files, so asking for recommendations is a possible second question.

Answer (score 1):

MigraDoc cannot modify PDF files. [PDFsharp can modify PDF files, but you did not tag PDFsharp.]

You can write an app that takes input from the user and then creates a PDF that already has all data in it.